# Counting number of rows in a dynamically changing web table in karate?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

Requirement is to count the number of rows available in a dynamically changing web table created using `<div>`. For this I tried using `waitForResultCount('.myClass', 4)` just to get the basics right of what is currently been displayed on the UI but couldn't get any help.

I want to see if the current value is updated in the table as a row or not, so want to know the updated count of the number of rows and match particular field in the corresponding rows. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find all instances of a chosen attribute. This is just an example, you can find other ways to identify each "row":

```
* def rows = locateAll("[tabulator-field]")
* print 'count:', rows.length
```

Comment: Hey, thanks @Peter Thomas, custom locators worked for me instead of a particular attribute, as the same web page was having similar attributes for multiple tables. Undoubtedly karate makes it a lot better. Thanks again!