# How to match an item in first row of a html table?

Tags: automation, karate

This is a snippet of the UI. Let me know to define to using karate automation.

```
<tr class="row" id="row0">
  <td class ="ID1">AXZ123</td>
  <td class ="ID2">AXZ456</td>
  <td class ="ID3">AXZ789</td>
     <input type="radio" "name=radio0">
```

I want to match AXYZ123 == locateAll("//tr..").

Please let me know the accurate way to define it.

Comment: Yes clicked tick mark as acceted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#tree-walking

```
* def rows = locateAll('tr')
* def firstRow = rows[0]
* def temp = firstRow.firstChild.text
* print temp
```

Also refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640025/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894989/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/66044456/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/66707088/143475