ShadowRoot input textbox access issue in Karate UI
I'm trying to insert text into an input box identified as "streetAddress.unitNumber" but am unable to. The element is nested within two open shadow roots. Although I can click button elements within the same shadow root, I cannot insert text into the text boxes, which have identifiers separated by a period (.) such as "streetAddress.quickSearch".
Here's the JavaScript path I am using:
document.querySelector("#appContainer > crma")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ppma")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("#streetAddress\\.quickSearch")

In my Karate feature, I tried various methods (js path, selector, xpath) but still encountered the same error:
script("document.querySelector('#appContainer > crma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ppma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#streetAddress\\.quickSearch')
  .value='1234'")

Error:
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js eval failed twice:
document.querySelector('#appContainer > crma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ppma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#streetAddress.unitNumber')
  .value='1234',
error: [type: MAP, value: {type=object, subtype=error, className=TypeError, description=TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

Interestingly, the console output shows the query selector path with a single "" but is submitted with a double "\". No variation (single "", double "\" or none) changes the behavior.
Despite reviewing documentation and tutorials, I'm still stuck.
Using Playwright, I can write to the input box successfully:
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const container = document.querySelector('#appContainer');
  const firstShadowRoot = container.shadowRoot;
  const nestedContainer = firstShadowRoot.querySelector('ppma');
  const secondShadowRoot = nestedContainer.shadowRoot;
  const inputElement = secondShadowRoot.querySelector('#streetAddress\\.unitNumber');
  inputElement.value = '123';
});

However, the corresponding Karate test code fails:
script("document.querySelector('#appContainer > crma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ppma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#streetAddress\\.unitNumber')
  .value='1234'");

and also fails
* def script =
      """
      function() {
      val container = document.querySelector('#crma');
      val firstShadowRoot = container.shadowRoot;
      val nestedContainer = firstShadowRoot.querySelector('ppma');
      val secondShadowRoot = nestedContainer.shadowRoot;
      val inputElement = secondShadowRoot.querySelector('#streetAddress\\.unitNumber');
      inputElement.value = '777';
      }
      """
      * delay(2000)
      * driver.eval(script)

I've tried to reproduce this issue on sample/practice sites, but none have the specific element structure used in this circumstance (id: value1.value2)
Thanks,
JB18

my first recommendation is to identify if karate has any bugs in processing the selector. there is not much any one can do if they can't replicate - so see if you can provide at least a jsfiddle simulation, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76680593/143475 - finally, see if tree-walking gives you a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66707088/143475

I finally found the answer
It requires 4 x backslash “\” to escape a special character (in this case, a period (.) within a string. This ensures that the character is interpreted literally rather than as a special character.
See working script below:
script("document.querySelector('#appContainer > crma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ppma')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#streetAddress\\\\.unitNumber')
  .value='1234'");

